# Azure Migration of Resources To New Account Before Deletion of User Account

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I had one doubt regarding resource management via Azure Portal.
Although, I am aware that migration to another subscription and tenant is possible along with movement of resources between resource groups but I am not sure if the access to resources will still remain available after I add someone via access control but the account giving access itself gets deleted or removed.

I wanted to know if it was possible to migrate the resources with full permissions to another user account if some account is removed from Azure which was used to create the resources in first place.

Comment: Please also mention any conditions or limitation with respect to resource type if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account used to create a resource is no longer relevant after the resource is created.  Other than the activity log entry, Azure doesn't track who created a resource, and if that original user account is deleted it will have no effect on the resource or any other user's access to it.